# Is there touch screen support in QGIS for Windows?

Tags: qgis, zoom

I have a new 2in1 PC (laptop and tablet).

It would be very nice to navigate in QGIS using its touch screen I.e. zoom in and zoom out using double finger touch, like on a mobile phone, etc.

Maybe it is already available?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this functionality is already available. There is a **Touch zoom and pan** tool right besides the regular Pan tool. I have a notebook with touch screen and both panning and pinch zooming works fine.

Comment: Note in QGIS 2.6 this is now part of the normal pan tool. So it will be one tool instead of two.